# data ordering issue in mysql for a particular column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table in which there is column name as mappedcloumnname and fieldname and my fieldcolumn contains `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `customerid`, `country` and `mappedcolumn`  contanins `c1-c20`. I wrote a query to sort my data based on `mappedcolumn` name but the order what am getting is wrong one

```
SELECT * FROM customermetadata 
   WHERE OrgID = in_orgid 
   ORDER BY MappedColumnName;
```

Comment: select * from customermetadata where OrgID=in_orgid  ORDER BY MappedColumnName ASC hope this help

Comment: i tried that too and am getting c1 in first row then instead of c2 am getting c10 in second row

Comment: see this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html  Please refers this hope this help

Comment: By the way, `SELECT 'c2' > 'c10'` is true. That means `c10` comes before `c2`.

Comment: Does your `mappedcolumn` always contain string that start with 'c' and the rest of the string is a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give it a try:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    customermetadata
WHERE
    OrgID = in_orgid
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(MappedColumnName FROM 2) AS UNSIGNED);
```

**Note:**

Here I've extracted the `number` from the `MappedColumnName` and sort the records based the extracted numbers.

I've created a demo where the table contains only two columns (`id` and `col`).

`col` column contains value like `c1,c2,...`.

[**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d26972/3/0) if you order by `col` only.

[**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d26972/2/0) if you order by extracting number from `col`.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to guess that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your column `MappedColumnName` contains value from `c1-c20`, then it will be treated as `String(VarChar)` in SQL and data will not be sorted properly.

Comment: then how to sort mappedcolumnname

Answer (score 0):

You should try in this way,

```
select * from customermetadata 
   where OrgID=in_orgid       
   Order By CAST(SUBSTR(MappedColumnName FROM 2 FOR LENGTH(MappedColumnName)) AS UNSIGNED);   ;
```

NOTE: A longer number is also a bigger number for numbers of the same length, you can make a textual comparison, because `'0' < '1' .... < '9'` and it will short Alpha-numeric order.